# Break Time Calculator

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am using Google Sheets to create a scheduler for my employees. One cell spits out a Total Estimated Time (X) to work.

In another cell, I want it to display:

"60" if X is less than 8
"80" if X is less than or equal to 10
"100" if X is less than or equal to 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use nested IF statements, like this:

`=IF(A2 < 8, 60, IF(A2 <= 10, 80, IF(A2 <= 12, 100)))`

This will produce the desired result of:

[image: output screenshot]

This works because the third argument to an `IF` statement is what happens when the expression is `FALSE`, which lets us continue exploring other cases. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {0.1, 60; 7.9, 80; 12, 100}, 2, 1)))
```

[image: 1]